# How to show it is differentiable?

Tags: calculus, analysis

> If $f(x)$ is continuous,and $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x > 0$, $xf(2x)-xf(x)=-2$. Than will it differentiable in $(0,\infty)$?

I got $xf(2x)=xf(x)-2$, than $f(x)=\frac{4}{x}+C$ there are any solution about this? I think it isn't differentiable at $f(a)$, than $f(2^n a)~(n=0,1,2,...)$ so there are infinitely many points that can't be differentiated. So it is hard to think about ...

Comment: @MartinR I'm sorry about missing condition.$ x>0$ , I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Your functional equation has solutions
$$ f(x) = \frac{4}{x} + g(\log_2(x))$$
where $g$ is any continuous periodic function on $\mathbb R$ with period $1$.
If $g$ is not differentiable, $f$ will not be differentiable either.

Comment: Thanks alot!! Is there are any other function with out this form? I'm curious about it...

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{l}\left( x \right)f'(2x)(2x)' + x'f(2x) - (xf'(x).x' + x'f(x))\\ = (x)(f'(2x)(2) + f(2x) - (xf'(x) + f(x)) = 0\\ = 2xf'(2x) + f(2x) - xf'(x) - f(x)\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaahqart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaadaqada
% qaaiaadIhaaiaawIcacaGLPaaacaWGMbGaai4jaiaacIcacaaIYaGa
% amiEaiaacMcacaGGOaGaaGOmaiaadIhacaGGPaGaai4jaiabgUcaRi
% aadIhacaGGNaGaamOzaiaacIcacaaIYaGaamiEaiaacMcacqGHsisl
% caGGOaGaamiEaiaadAgacaGGNaGaaiikaiaadIhacaGGPaGaaiOlai
% aadIhacaGGNaGaey4kaSIaamiEaiaacEcacaWGMbGaaiikaiaadIha
% caGGPaGaaiykaaqaaiabg2da9iaacIcacaWG4bGaaiykaiaacIcaca
% WGMbGaai4jaiaacIcacaaIYaGaamiEaiaacMcacaGGOaGaaGOmaiaa
% cMcacqGHRaWkcaWGMbGaaiikaiaaikdacaWG4bGaaiykaiabgkHiTi
% aacIcacaWG4bGaamOzaiaacEcacaGGOaGaamiEaiaacMcacqGHRaWk
% caWGMbGaaiikaiaadIhacaGGPaGaaiykaiabg2da9iaaicdaaeaacq
% GH9aqpcaaIYaGaamiEaiaadAgacaGGNaGaaiikaiaaikdacaWG4bGa
% aiykaiabgUcaRiaadAgacaGGOaGaaGOmaiaadIhacaGGPaGaeyOeI0
% IaamiEaiaadAgacaGGNaGaaiikaiaadIhacaGGPaGaeyOeI0IaamOz
% aiaacIcacaWG4bGaaiykaaaaaa!89C1!
$$
by the product,sum and function of a function rules.

Comment: This is incorrect. You cannot have $f'$ without knowing the differntiability of $f$.